# C Programming: Saving value in for loop and finding minimum

Tags: c

I have been sitting here for the past 5 hours trying to figure this out. I am new to C Programming.

I need to be able to compare the values in the for loops and store them, and in the end print out which store has the cheapest price with the correlating store #. Here is what I have, and it keeps giving me weird outputs and not adding up orders correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int shops = 0, ingredients = 0, i=0, j=0, cstore=0;
    double temp = 0.0, ingredientPrice = 0.0, total, cprice=0.0;

    printf("How many shops will you be visiting?\n");
    scanf("%d",&shops);

    for(i = 0; i < shops; i++){
        printf("You are at shop # %d\n",i+1);
        printf("How many ingredients do you need at shop #%d?\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d",&ingredients);

        for(j = 0; j < ingredients; j++) {
            printf("How much is ingredient #%d?\n", j+1);
            scanf("%lf", &temp);
            ingredientPrice += temp;
            total = ingredientPrice;

            if (shops == 1) {
                cstore = shops;
                cprice = total;
            }
            else if(total < ingredientPrice) {
                cstore = i+1;
                cprice = total;
            }
        }
        printf("Your total at shop #%d is $%lf\n", i+1, total);
    }
    printf("Your cheapest order was at shop #%d and cost $%lf.\n", cstore, cprice);
    return 0;
}
```

As a side note, cannot use arrays, as we aren't on that chapter yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please and thanks

Also here is the assignment in case anyone needs clarity on what I'm asking:

Your mentor has tasked you with going to several different stores to place orders. This program should ask for the total number of shops that will be visited. At each shop, ask for the number of ingredients that need to be purchases. For each ingredient, ask for the price. Keep track of the total for the order so that you can write it down before leaving the shop. This program
should also track with order was the cheapest and which shop the cheapest order was at. This will help your mentor decide who to keep doing business with!

Input Specification
1. The number of shops will be a positive integer.
2. The number of ingredients will be a positive integer.
3. The cost for each ingredient will be a positive real number.

Output Specification
Output the cost at each shop to two decimal places.

Your total at #Y is $X.XX.

At the end of the program, print the cheapest order.

Your cheapest order was at shop #Y and cost $X.XX.

Output Sample

How many shops will you be visiting?
3
You are at shop #1.
How many ingredients do you need at shop #1?
2
How much is ingredient #1?
3.5
How much is ingredient #2?
10
Your total at shop #1 is $13.50.
You are at shop #2.
How many ingredients do you need at shop #2?
3
How much is ingredient #1?
2.75
How much is ingredient #2?
3
How much is ingredient #3?
1.25
Your total at shop #2 is $7.00.
You are at shop #3.
How many ingredients do you need at shop #3?
2
How much is ingredient #1?
4
How much is ingredient #2?
5
Your total at shop #3 is $9.00.
Your cheapest order was at shop #2 and cost $7.00.

Comment: You should not use `scanf()` without checking the return value.

Comment: I'm sorry can you please elaborate? I don't understand which value you're speaking about.

Comment: Because you did not read `scanf()`'s documentation, and your instructor did not bother to tell you that it does return a value and that it has a very important meaning and that you should be careful with it.

Comment: sscanf () article on line. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

Comment: (Hint: printf the value you think you just scanf'd in)

Comment: I tried @IharobAlAsimi code down there in the answer, however it doesn't output correctly either. I am still very confused in what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Read over this possible solution. I did not bother to check the return value of `scanf()` but then I am lazy and don't use it for production code anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int    i = 0, shops = 0;
    int    cstore = 0;          // current minimum store
    double cprice = 0.0;        // total for the current minimum store

    printf("How many shops will you be visiting?\n");
    scanf("%d", &shops);

    for (i = 1; i <= shops; i++){
        int    j = 0, ingredients = 0;
        double total = 0.0;      // total for the current store.

        printf("You are at shop # %d\n", i);
        printf("How many ingredients do you need at shop #%d?\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &ingredients);

        // get the prices of the ingredients at this store and total them up.
        for (j = 1; j <= ingredients; j++) {
            double ingredientPrice = 0.0;

            printf("How much is ingredient #%d?\n", j);
            scanf("%lf", &ingredientPrice);
            total += ingredientPrice;
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            // this is the first store so it is automatically the lowest thus far being the only one.
            cstore = i;
            cprice = total;
        }
        else if (total < cprice && ingredients > 0) {
            // the total for this store is less than the last known smallest total so lets update our variables.
            // if there are zero ingredients from this store then it does not count.
            cstore = i;
            cprice = total;
        }
        // the currency is US dollars with two decimal places.
        printf("Your total at shop #%d is $%.2lf and the lowest store is %d for $%.2lf.\n", i, total, cstore, cprice);
    }
    printf("Your cheapest order was at shop #%d and cost $%.2lf.\n", cstore, cprice);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this output.

```
How many shops will you be visiting?
3
You are at shop # 1
How many ingredients do you need at shop #1?
2
How much is ingredient #1?
3
How much is ingredient #2?
4
Your total at shop #1 is $7.00 and the lowest store is 1 for $7.00.
You are at shop # 2
How many ingredients do you need at shop #2?
3
How much is ingredient #1?
1
How much is ingredient #2?
3
How much is ingredient #3?
4
Your total at shop #2 is $8.00 and the lowest store is 1 for $7.00.
You are at shop # 3
How many ingredients do you need at shop #3?
3
How much is ingredient #1?
1
How much is ingredient #2?
2
How much is ingredient #3?
2
Your total at shop #3 is $5.00 and the lowest store is 3 for $5.00.
Your cheapest order was at shop #3 and cost $5.00.
```

Comment: @TawhidChowdhury glad I could help. Just accept this as an answer and that will be fine.

Comment: @TawhidChowdhury by the way I have found that adding comments will help you to understand what the code is doing. Often when I write some code and then start writing the comments, I realize that the code is wrong or there was something that I forgot about. Source code is designed more for computers than for humans and thinking with comments is a lot easier than trying to think with code.

Comment: @TawhidChowdhury also notice that I tried to limit the scope of variables as much as possible. Whenever you open up a new scope with braces you can use variables that are only visible within that new scope. I prefer to limit scope of variables as much as possible and to use as unique names for variables as is reasonable. I suggest you compare what I wrote to what you wrote to understand the logic errors you had introduced into your code.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I was confused as to how I would compare the price of each store if the cprice = total. Now I understand that the if statement initializes the first statement and makes store 1 the first cprice, and then each loop checks the statement and changes the cstore to that number if its total is lower than the previous cprices and saves that value. I hope I am understanding that correctly.

Comment: @TawhidChowdhury sounds like you understand the logic well. The key for you right now is to always understand what the problem domain logic should be first and then express that logic in the actual programming language, the solution domain. In your case you first want to think about visiting stores and collecting ingredient prices at each store. The first thing to do is to try to model this as concretely as possible in order to understand what the logic of your source code should be. If you don't understand the problem you are not going to be able to write a good program to solve it.

Comment: @TawhidChowdhury also it looks like there is a logic error in this program. What if the first store has zero ingredients?

Answer (score -1):

Just initialize `cprice` to a reasonably large value, and then after each order just compare that variable with the total and update it if it's larger.

One simple and safe trick and since ammounts must be positive would be to make `cprice = -1` to enable checking if it was initialized or not yet.

Regarding your other problem, it seems that your code is invoking undefined behavior most likely due to the wrong use of the `scanf()` function.

This is an example of how you can do it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int shops = 0, ingredients = 0, i = 0, j = 0, cstore = 0;
    double temp = 0.0, ingredientPrice = 0.0, total = 0.0, cprice = -1.0;

    printf("How many shops will you be visiting?\n");
    scanf("%d", &shops);

    for (i = 0; i < shops; i++){
        printf("You are at shop # %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("How many ingredients do you need at shop #%d?\n", i + 1);

        scanf("%d", &ingredients);
        for (j = 0; j < ingredients; j++) {
            printf("How much is ingredient #%d?\n", j + 1);
            scanf("%lf", &temp);
            ingredientPrice += temp;
            total = ingredientPrice;
            if (shops == 1) {
                cstore = shops;
                cprice = total;
            } else if (total < ingredientPrice) {
                cstore = i + 1;
                cprice = total;
            }
        }

        if ((cprice < 0.0) || (cprice > total)) {
            cprice = total;
            cstore = i;
        }
        printf("Your total at shop #%d is $%lf\n", i + 1, total);
    }
    printf("Your cheapest order was at shop #%d and cost $%lf.\n", cstore, cprice);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't really think that your `scanf()`'s will cause undefined behavior because you carefully initialized everything. But that doesn't mean it's the right or correct way to do this, instead you should check the success of `scanf()` to ensure that input was valid.

Comment: "reasonably large value". Don't do that. EVER it's NOT gonna work and SHOULD NOT be practised

Comment: @Fureeish I beg you to read the question, and reasonable large in case you can't estimate such a value at compile time use `INT_MAX` or the equivalent. Also, there is no reason to make this more complicated.

Comment: It's true that it will work. It's false that there is no reason to make this more complicated. People should not be taught to practice bad habits just becuase "it's simple and will work now. Later you will learn to never do it". Yes, it's sometimes done, because things need to be sometimes simplified, but not here. Either do max value of a double or check when is the 1st input done, then, change the value of `total` to that

Comment: @Fureeish I agree partially, learning is an incremental process and specially in programming. I do agree that bad habits should be out of the process from the very beginning.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, but unfortunately I am still rather confused. PS, i'm in COP3223C (intro to C Programming). So please bear with me. So how would I code it so that whenever the loop runs, it only stores the price for the cheapest store? I added the homework assignment problem in my original post if that helps anyone understand my question.

Comment: @TawhidChowdhury please see the example of your code fixed to do what you need.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into codeblocks program and ran it, but I get this with the inputs:

How many shops will you be visiting?
2
You are at shop # 1
How many ingredients do you need at shop #1?
1
How much is ingredient #1?
1
Your total at shop #1 is $1.000000
You are at shop # 2
How many ingredients do you need at shop #2?
2
How much is ingredient #1?
1
How much is ingredient #2?
2
Your total at shop #2 is $4.000000
Your cheapest order was at shop #0 and cost $1.000000.

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 12.392 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be adding the loops correctly, and then the shop # isn't correct. I